# Why is the while loop running even when the condition is false?

Tags: javascript, loops, do-while

I am new to JavaScript and learning it's basics right now. I come accross do...while loop which explains that 'do' command will run once and then the condition would be checked. Now here is my code:
// Setup

```
const myArray = [];
let i = 10;


do {

}
while (i < 5) 
{
  myArray.push(i);
  i++;
}

console.log(myArray);
```

Since there is no element in the do, it shouldn't add anything in myArray. However, the end results shows 10 in myArray and I am confused why is it happening? Please assist.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what did you expect a `do { } while (..) { ... }` construct to do? It's either `do .. while`, or `while ..`, but `do .. while ..` is… what?

Answer (score 5):

More about [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) and [do while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while)

```js
const myArray = [];
let i = 10;

// this is a do while loop
do {

}
while (i < 5) 


// this is a block unrelated to the loop
{
  myArray.push(i);
  i++;
}

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: Also point out even if the code existed in the `do while` block, the could would be run once.